# Issue with loading image php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, loading

I am new to jquery and I want a loading image with Ajax post.I did the following

I have a form as below-

```
 <form id="ajaxquery" method="post" action="">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">


            <td>
                <label for="field">Gender:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0" > GROOM
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" > BRIDE 
            </td>
             <td>
                <label for="field">Select country:</label>
                <select name="Countryname" id="country">
                    <option>select country</option>
                <?php foreach ($country as $countryname): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $countryname['country_id'];?>"><?php echo $countryname['country_name']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>



    </form>
```

And loading image div

```
 <div id="overlay"><div><img src="../images/loader.gif" width="64px" height="64px"/></div></div>
```

Script

```
$("#ajaxquery").on( "submit" , function(){

    // Intercept the form submission
    var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

    // Post data to your PHP processing script
    $.post( "", formdata, function( data ) { 
        **beforeSend: function(){$("#overlay").show();},**
        // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
        history.pushState(null, "", "testdup.php");
         $("#success").empty();
        $("#success").html ( data );
    });

    return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting
});

$('.pagination').on( "click" , function(){

         $("#success").empty();


});

</script>
```

When I submit form loading image will show until the data return. But now loading image is always show.i am very new to jquery. Please help me.

Comment: means after completing ajax request also image is showing right??

Comment: Is `**beforeSend: function(){$("#overlay").show();},**` written as is in your code ? Also, I dont see any call to [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: @kranthi:yes..how to solve this issue?please help me

Comment: @SergeK. yes ..

Comment: Do you have any error in your console ?

Comment: Use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you want to use `beforeSend ` option

Comment: @SergeK.nop..loading image show after completing ajax request

Comment: I dont know this syntax `**beforeSend: ...**`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery offers event handlers for finished ajax requests, which can be chained to the actual request itself. The function that is submitted to the post as a parameter is the first success handler.

```
$.post( "", formdata, function(data){
    //successhandler
}).done(function(data){
    //successhandler
}).fail(function(data){
    //failure handler
}).always(function(){
    //This is called regardless if the request was a success or not
});
```

Your problem can be solved with the `always` handler, because you want the loading indicator to hide whether or not the request was successfull.

```
$("#overlay").show();
$.post( "", formdata, function( data ) { 
    // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
    history.pushState(null, "", "testdup.php");
     $("#success").empty();
    $("#success").html ( data );
}).always(function(){
    $("#overlay").hide();
});
```

Keep in mind, that you should use the `fail` handler as well to show your user, that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div id="overlay"><div><img src="../images/loader.gif" width="64px" height="64px"/></div></div>
```

to

```
 <div id="overlay" style='display:none;'><div><img src="../images/loader.gif" width="64px" height="64px"/></div></div>






$("#overlay").show();
$.post( "", formdata, function( data ) { 

    history.pushState(null, "", "testdup.php");

    $("#success").empty();
    $("#success").html ( data );
}).always(function(){
     $("#overlay").hide();
});
```